# SlidingPaneLayout - how to always show a little part of slide out view (like in hangouts)

Tags: android, slidingpanelayout

I'm using a simple `SlidingPaneLayout` and what I want is following:

I want, that a little bit of the slide out view is always visible, so that the user always see's, that there exists something to pull out... Like it is in Hangouts.

Is that somehow possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to set a left margin on the slideable view (top view)

e.g.: `android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"`

Comment: that works. Although, i could swaer, i did try that already and it just showed a border but not the view below... But, it works, so thanks a lot

Comment: this works only once, at start. If you close the `SlidingPaneLayout` it closes entirely !

Comment: Thank you!  This helped a lot.

Answer (score -2):

You use **showcase** to notify the user about something available to be pulled out. Which will make your app looks more professional.

https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView

Comment: I know about this library... Actually, I think, it looks better if a visible pullable area exists... Especially in a bigger app, where not every view has this menu... And I personally like the look of Hangouts

Comment: Umm .. did you try using frame layout and adding an image that looks like a pull on the left of the screen?

Comment: Actually, I want that the slide out area is partly visible... I treid using padding, transparent background and similar, but I was not able to get the desired result... a pullable bar on the side is no problem though, but that's not what I want...

Comment: Could whomever downvoted this answer include a reason why, as StackOverflow asks? I certainly hope people didn't downvote this because of their personal tastes in ascetics—how pathetic!